# Using the go/ast package

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm attempting to do some metaprogramming in Go and I'm trying to use the `go/ast` package.

Here's the snippet which is creating the AST:

```
// Create an AST
fooFn := &ast.FuncDecl{
    Name: &ast.Ident{Name: "foofn"},
    Body: &ast.BlockStmt{
        List: []ast.Stmt{&ast.ExprStmt{
            X: &ast.CallExpr{
                Fun: &ast.Ident{Name: "println"},
                Args: []ast.Expr{
                    &ast.BasicLit{Kind: token.INT, Value: "42"},
                },
            },
        }},
    },
}

f := &ast.File{
    Name:  &ast.Ident{Name: "foopackage"},
    Decls: []ast.Decl{fooFn},
    Scope: &ast.Scope{
        Objects: map[string]*ast.Object{
            "Foo": &ast.Object{
                Kind: ast.Fun,
                Name: "Foo",
                Decl: fooFn,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

See the full code here http://play.golang.org/p/zTJdnqVx__ which should produce this output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0x773ae]

goroutine 16 [running]:
runtime.panic(0x18b5a0, 0x24c8af)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:279 +0x120
go/ast.(*FuncType).Pos(0x0, 0x1c827eb4, 0xfefd02b8, 0x10422360)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/go/ast/ast.go:446 +0x2e
go/ast.(*FuncDecl).Pos(0x10422360, 0x10422360, 0x47, 0xfeee1cb0)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/go/ast/ast.go:933 +0x40
go/printer.(*printer).declList(0x10402840, 0x1040e108, 0x1, 0x1)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/go/printer/nodes.go:1587 +0x180
go/printer.(*printer).file(0x10402840, 0x10442080)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/go/printer/nodes.go:1597 +0x1e0
go/printer.(*printer).printNode(0x10402840, 0x184ba0, 0x10442080, 0x104223c0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/go/printer/printer.go:1087 +0xa40
go/printer.(*Config).fprint(0xfeee1e90, 0xfefd02d8, 0x10426180, 0x104181b0, 0x184ba0, 0x10442080, 0x104223c0, 0xfefd02d8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/go/printer/printer.go:1226 +0xc0
go/printer.(*Config).Fprint(0xfeee1e90, 0xfefd02d8, 0x10426180, 0x104181b0, 0x184ba0, 0x10442080, 0x0, 0x0)
    /tmp/sandbox/go/src/pkg/go/printer/printer.go:1284 +0xa0
main.main()
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-eb231fa6_4e4e43ec_79a6f993_ce4170ce_07ee185b/prog.go:46 +0x8c0
```

---

Edit: here is the working version with `FuncDelc.Type` set and `Scope` removed (since I'm only after the source code buffer):

#### http://play.golang.org/p/B0Xp61rSce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may need to provide an `ast.FuncType` to your `ast.FuncDecl`. The error appears to be a result of calling `IsValid()` on the `Func` property of your (nil) `FuncType`.

Comment: Thanks! that was it :) I was so close